# Cisco AnyConnect VPN, install issue, vpnui not executing

Tags: networking, xubuntu, vpn

I was able to install Cisco VPN AnyConnect client with no issue in Linux Mint 17.  However, in Xubuntu 14.04, I get the following issue when I run, sudo sh ./vpn_install.sh:
 
`Do you accept the terms in the license agreement? [y/n] y
You have accepted the license agreement.
Please wait while Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client is being installed...
Removing previous installation...
/opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh: 76: /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpn_uninstall.sh: /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/manifesttool: not found
mv: cannot stat ‘/opt/cisco/vpn/*.log’: No such file or directory
Starting Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Agent...
/etc/init.d/vpnagentd: 41: /etc/init.d/vpnagentd: /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnagentd: not found
brock@brock-xubuntu:~/Downloads/anyconnect-3.1.06073/vpn$`

The files that it says are 'not found' are actually there.

Then when I try to start the program via GUI I get: 
[image]

In terminal I get:
`brock@brock-xubuntu:/$ /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui
bash: /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui: No such file or directory`

And, I would be fine with using network-manager-vpnc to handle it if that would be the only solution.  I only wouldn't know where to place the xml profile file from my institution.

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to connect by using OpenConnect. I recommend setting an alias for the following given it is a long command.

```
sudo openconnect --usergroup UserGroupName -u UserName VPNAddressOfMyInstitution.edu --no-cert-check
```

(You may not need to add the `--no-cert-check` argument.)